# Stop while Loop by GPIO INPUT in Python

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I am writing a program in python on RaspberryPi, to stop While loop through GPIO input.

I don't know why it is not working.

Can you please look on my coding and guide me to resolved it?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

x = GPIO.input(17)

while x == True:
    print ("ONONONONONONONONONON")

print ("OFF")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `x` with the value of `GPIO.input(17)` *at the time of the initialization*.  It won't change after that unless you assign something new to it, e.g.:

```
x = GPIO.input(17)

while x == True:
    print ("ONONONONONONONONONON")
    x = GPIO.input(17)
```

Now x will be updated for each iteration.  You could also just use:

```
while GPIO.input(17) == True:
    print ("ONONONONONONONONONON")
```

You should put some kind of passive delay into the loop too, however, or else this will busy loop the processor (i.e., run it up to 100% constantly).  How long that can be depends on how you are changing the value of the GPIO; if you are turning it off, 1 or 2 seconds is fine.  However, if it is just a momentary change you are looking for (e.g., a button push), the gap will have to be shorter (say 200 ms) so you don't miss it.

Comment: On your first coding it is giving me error of defining value of x,
but your second code is working perfectly

Comment: I'm actually not much of a python user, but that seems strange; x should be mutable.  Anyway, the basic logic error is assuming that x is going to change automatically when the value of the GPIO does; there's no way to do that, you actually have to check it via the `GPIO.input()` function call.

Comment: @goldilocks When x == True is first encountered x is not defined.  It's not defined until the x = GPIO.input(17) line.

Comment: @joan Ah, I didn't mean for the previous code to be removed, I was just showing the loop (so I've edited that back in).  Good catch.